# Power BI: Measure is not ignoring Slicer Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

My Dax Query is correctly bringing back the expected data. The one caveat, I can't seem to ignore an outside slicer to the visual for this one particular calculation. What am I doing wrong?

```
xxPY_TrafficSum = CALCULATE (
    [xPY_TrafficSum],
    DATESBETWEEN (
        DimDate[FullDate],
        DATE (
            YEAR ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ) - 2,
            MONTH ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ),
            DAY ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ) + 1
        ),
        DATE (
            YEAR ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ) - 1,
            MONTH ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ),
            DAY ( ALLSELECTED ( DimDate[FullDate] ) ) + 1
        )
    ),
    ALL ( DimDate[IsLastDayOfMonth], DimDate[IsLastDayOfMonth] )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to specify the column twice within the ALL function. Although I am not sure how this would affect the calculation, you can give it a try:

```
All(DimDate[IsLastDayOfMonth])
```

One more thing you could try is to move the position of the `ALL` function within the calculation. i.e) switch the positions of the `DATESBETWEEN` and the ALL functions. If your issue is still not resolved, it would be great if you can share a sample data/file for us to look at.